innerscript does not work with most recent LuaLaTeX
I recently upgraded my computer to the newest version of LaTeX2e. Unfortunately, the most recent version 1.2 of the innerscript package no longer works. The following LaTeX file produces an error under the current version of LuaLaTeX.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{innerscript}

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}


Here is the beginning of the log file.

Command Line:   lualatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "temp.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\temporary

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.1 (MiKTeX 24.4)
restricted system commands enabled.
(./temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(C:/Users/axler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/Users/axler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(C:/Users/axler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/lualatex/innerscript/innerscr
ipt.sty
! Missing math style, treated as \displaystyle.
<to be read again> 
\crampedisplaystyle 
l.718   \Umathcloseordspacing\crampedisplaystyle
                                              =\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
? 


I also tried typesetting the simple file above on Overleaf (set to use the 2024 version of LuaLaTeX) and got the same error message. However, if I ask Overleaf to use the 2023 version of LuaLaTeX, then the error disappears. Thus it appears to me that innerscript does not work with the most recent version of LuaLaTeX.
Does anyone have a patch for innerscript that may fix this problem?
Thanks!

I pinged the author.

This is not due to changes to LaTeX, but to changes to innerscript which introduced a bug. The fix is very simple to make in the package. I'm not sure if the following has side-effects or not, but adding
\let\crampedisplaystyle\crampeddisplaystyle
\usepackage{innerscript}

at least allows a minimal example to compile without error.
The patch needed in the .sty or .dtx file is just to correct the typo by inserting the missing d.
--- tex/lualatex/innerscript/innerscript.sty    2023-11-09 22:17:01.000000000 +0000
+++ /tmp/innerscript.sty        2024-07-31 03:27:19.773624022 +0100
@@ -715,7 +715,7 @@
   \IS@info{Adding space after closing delimiters.}
   \Umathcloseordspacing\displaystyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
   \Umathcloseordspacing\textstyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
-  \Umathcloseordspacing\crampedisplaystyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
+  \Umathcloseordspacing\crampeddisplaystyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
   \Umathcloseordspacing\crampedtextstyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.5}
   \ifnum\IS@script>0
     \Umathcloseordspacing\scriptstyle=\scalemu{\thinmuskip}{0.3}

